# Fluid resizing input in Bootstrap 3 navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want my input in the bootstrap navbar to have the maximum width possible without breaking the single row design and the mobile toggle on collapse.

`col-sm-*` is working on the button but not on the input.  I'm trying to avoid `flex-box` and stick with pre-existing Boostrap classes if possible.

---

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="navbar-header">                     
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><em>FirstShop.com</em></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <form action="">
            <div class="form-group">                                
              <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-5">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-sm-1">Submit</button>                                
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[Also prepared a live demo here.](http://www.bootply.com/u7KLzx0Cou)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, inputs have 100% width set, so the wrap is caused by your submit button.  One way to address this is to use an [**input group**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups), which will allow you to have the button element inline with the input.

Replace your form with the following markup:

**HTML:**

```
      <form class="navform">
        <div class="input-group">            
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-info" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Submit</button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </form>
```

I also added a navform class to give the form the same height as the default navbar and added padding to make the input align to the middle of the navbar.

**CSS:**

```
.navform {
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*You can wrap your input in a specific sized div :*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/UmwelBa4tU

**HTML** :

```
  <form action="" class="">
    <div class="row">           
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control ">              
      </div>    

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-sm-1">Submit</button>                                
    </div>
  </form>
```